# Move nodes by x and by y at the same time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to create a game with rectangles which move by x and by y.
My question is: Have I move the view (viewer of the player) or have I move the rectangles by x and by y at the same time?

I tried to move rectangles by x and by y at the same time, with the following code, but the rectangles move only by y.

```
@objc func addRects() {

    rects = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: rects) as! [String]

    rect = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: rects[0])

    rect.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 256 + 320, y: self.frame.height / 256)
    rect.size = CGSize(width: 180, height: 120)
    rect.zPosition = 1

    self.addChild(rect)

    moveByX = SKAction.moveTo(x: -500, duration: 2.0)
    moveByY = SKAction.moveTo(y: -800, duration: 2.0)
    removeRects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0)

    rect.run(SKAction.sequence([moveByY,moveByY]))
    rect.run(SKAction.sequence([wait,removeRects]))
}
```

How can I resolve this problem ?
Thank you

Comment: Typo: rect.run(SKAction.sequence([moveByY,moveByY]))
 should be rect.run(SKAction.sequence([moveByX,moveByY]))

Comment: And you should use a different `SKAction` function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417768-move

Comment: @luk2302 I suspect this is the SKAction he should be using with values like -500, -800  and the fact that is variables are named moveBy https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417722-moveby

Comment: @RonMyschuk You might be correct.

Comment: Thank you, but Can I set different duration for x and y ?

Comment: if you need different durations keep doing it the way you are. (group vs sequence would run both actions at the same time)

Comment: I want to make some rows of rectangles and this rows have to move down

Comment: Ok I've just found a solution, I have to move down the view and generate the rows of rectangles. But, how can I move down the view?

Comment: I mean like piano tiles, when you click a tile the game view move up.            
      I do not know if I explain

Comment: Ok I understood, I'll post the code when I end it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a sequence:

```
rect.run(moveByY)
rect.run(moveByX)
```

then it should move at the same time "moveByY" and "moveByX"

The other problem is, that you used:

> rect.run(SKAction.sequence([moveByY,moveByY]))

I Hope my answer helps!